# Getting toggleClass to remain for any viewer of the site

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, toggle

How can I get toggleClass to save and remain for any viewers of the site? Here is a non-working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/715j94gL/3/

```
    $(function(){
        $(".worker").click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("active");        
        }); 
        });
```

I thought of using cookies but that will only save for one viewer of the site on their computer.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: You will need a server to save state across multiple users. Each user has her own client, this is the wrong location to save across users.

Comment: at my job we all have to call or yell to this one guy who hands out the work. With this, we could toggle our name and he could check and see who needs work. Or more intuitively a browser tab alert could be sent when somebody needs work, then he could just click to toggle that person as "has work" @Cruiser

Comment: Database or file that saves the employees name and their work status. Website where employee can click to say they're out of work. Website where the foreman can see all employees status. Add extra functionality like automatic notifications later.

Comment: @Bandon James see my solution below

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see it, you have two options here - both come with a few pitfalls.

### Database

Store the current class of the element in a database. For every viewer that visits your site, load the class from said database. Use ajax with a timer to retrieve the class from the database if you want to 'live' update it.

http://www.formget.com/insert-data-in-database-using-php/

### Ajax

Store the current class in a text file (if you're going to store multiple values for multiple elements, such as each of your co-workers, storing your data in the JSON format will make it easier to retrieve and save). Exactly the same as above - probably not the preferred method (but worth mentioning as it is a possibility, I guess).

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/
http://www.sitepoint.com/ajaxjquery-getjson-simple-example/

### Pitfalls

Your users are going to 'fight' over the class of the element. Imagine if you have 5 - 10 people all simultaneously toggling the class whilst it is broadcasting live. It's going to get very distracting. Just something to be aware of.

Comment: Ajax to retrieve from a text file will be a nice option here since we don't know if OP has a server or if it is only a HTML + CSS + Javascript project.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I guess I will need a lot more knowledge to complete this project. Where should I start? I think I will go with the Ajax approach. regarding the "fight" there are only about 10 people that will be using this and requests are usually made every hour buy someone different

Comment: If the link to the jquery API for jQuery.getJSON() doesn't help much, try this link - http://www.sitepoint.com/ajaxjquery-getjson-simple-example/ - it walks you through an example. This seems like a good project for learning about such features, as it sounds like a good use-case for JSON/AJAX.

Comment: @Lewis Thanks again. I am reading up on JSON/AJAX now. big help ty

Answer (score 0):

Well this can not be achieved unless you send some request to the server and save the stated to server side variable like session:

```
$(function(){
    $(".worker").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("active"); 
        $.get('setState.aspx?' + $(this).hasClass('active')?"1":0");       
    }); 
    });
```

Comment: thanks for the help, what else would I need to add? I have added this to the fiddle with no luck.

Comment: well this an example of sending the state to the server. you have to have a plage like `setState.aspx` or `setState.php` or what ever language you use that gets the stat and saves it into the session and when loading the page if session value is true you set the active class

Comment: Do you have a link or guide I could use to help implement this? I am having trouble with the link Lewis provided

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a JSON file like this:

```
{"employees" : {
    "name": "Bob",
    "needsWork": false
    }
}
```

When you click the button, have the jquery update the "needsWork" property of the employee. When the page loads, ajax the json with $.getJSON and set the class based on whether "needsWork" is true.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I am now reading the link Lewis has provided regarding JSON for me to understand how to implement this.